# Differences between Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

I'm reading Weinberg's paper on "Dynamics at Infinite Momentum" in which he proves a claim about the type of Feynman diagram that contributes finitely to the perturbation series and the type that contributes 0 in the infinite momentum frame. However, I don't understand the differences between the following set of diagrams. How does the propagator in diagram B bending make the diagram different?

[image]

Comment: Try doing a careful read of Section IV. As the text points out, the left-right ordering of the vertices matters (note this is different between A and B). In particular, the text mentions that the theta function in rule (b) means some diagrams that appear in "normal" perturbation theory will be zero in the infinite momentum frame.

Comment: Okay thank you. We are to ignore diagrams with particles that are created or destroyed out of the vacuum. How do you tell from a diagram if that is the case? I’m not entirely sure what an ordered diagram is either. 

But is this the reasoning? : If you have diagrams with lines coming in from the right (left), merging and going back right (left), some of the $\eta$s are going to be negative. Furthermore, this situation corresponds physically to particles being created out of and destroyed into a vacuum.

Comment: To be honest I am not an expert on this kind of calculation and was just reading through the paper. But, your reasoning is what I understood from reading as well.

Comment: This is sufficient, I think. I am studying the BFSS conjecture of M theory. I just needed to know what the IMF is and I came across this paper.